# Hibernate mappedBy and @JoinColumn

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, java-ee-7

When I trying to get One To Many and Many To One relationships, I got problem with the join column on the vehicle table .. Why hibernate is searching for column USER_ID instead of joining it to the table ? I know the purpose of joining but when I tried to use it with mapped By attribute I got this error . What is wrong with that code ?

Exception that i got :

> > Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'USER_ID' in 'field list'

Users table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

public User(){}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirst_name() {
    return first_name;
}

public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
    this.first_name = first_name;
}

public int getSalary() {
    return salary;
}

public void setSalary(int salary) {
    this.salary = salary;
}

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "User{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", first_name='" + first_name + '\'' +
            ", salary=" + salary +
            ", last_name=" + last_name +
            '}';
}

public Collection<Vehicle> getVehicles() {
    return vehicles;
}

public void setVehicles(Collection<Vehicle> vehicles) {
    this.vehicles = vehicles;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();

public Collection<Address> getAddresses() {
    return addresses;
}
public void setAddresses(Collection<Address> addresses) {
    this.addresses = addresses;
}

    @ElementCollection // for saving the collection or persist it to database
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id")) // will add to the fk created table renamed column "fk_user_id"
    private Collection<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String first_name;
    @Column(name = "salary")
    private int salary;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String last_name;
 }
```

Vehicle:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
public class Vehicle {

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
private User user;

public int getVehicle_id() {
    return vehicle_id;
}

public void setVehicle_id(int vehicle_id) {
    this.vehicle_id = vehicle_id;
}

public String getVehicle_name() {
    return vehicle_name;
}

public void setVehicle_name(String vehicle_name) {
    this.vehicle_name = vehicle_name;
}

@Id
private int vehicle_id;
private String vehicle_name;

}
```

Comment: does your Vehicle table have USER_ID column?

Comment: No! vehicle_id and vehicle_name , @Join Column is basically rename the existence column ?

Comment: As i understand it can join column to a table and can rename it .. i have user_id column in mine users table;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are treating `@JoinColumn` a bit differently that you think.

When you have a config:

```
public class Vehicle {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
  private User user;
```

It tells the persistence provider to use `VEHICLE.USER_ID` column when the `VEHICLE` and `USERS` tables are being joined.

By default on the `USERS` table side, the primary key is used, which in this case is a column with the same name: `USERS.USER_ID` (unless you specify explicitly `referencedColumnName` property i the `@JoinColumn`).

The bottom line is that you need to have a `user_id` column in your VEHICLE table.